# sql query to find users with at least 2 types of accounts

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlplus

I'm new to relational sql. I'm trying to figure out a query to return the names of customers who have more than one type of account.

customers:

```
+------------+--------------+ 
| cid        | Name         | 
+------------+--------------+ 
| 1          | Bob          |
| 2          | John         | 
| 3          | Jane         | 
+------------+--------------+
```

accounts:

```
+------------+--------------+ 
| aid        | type         | 
+------------+--------------+ 
| 1          | Checking     |
| 2          | Saving       | 
| 3          | CD           | 
+------------+--------------+
```

transactions:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+ 
| tid        | cid          | aid          | 
+------------+--------------+--------------+ 
| 1          | 1            | 1            | 
| 2          | 2            | 1            | 
| 3          | 1            | 2            | 
| 4          | 2            | 3            | 
| 5          | 3            | 1            | 
+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

With these tables, the query should return Bob and John. I'm having some trouble with how to write such a query. More specifically, how do I keep count of how many accounts a customer has and how do I compare if the accounts are different without adding a new column to the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this seems to work in SQL Fiddle with my test data structure.  Try it out with your real data structure and see if it gives you what you're looking for.

```
SELECT name FROM customers c WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT DISTINCT aid FROM transactions
  WHERE cid = c.cid
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT aid)>1
)
```

Comment: Oh my. I completely forgot about DISTINCT! Thank you so much!